# add confirmation alert in ignited data table actions

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I am using ignited datatable for my application.I have added action as below

```
$this->datatables->add_column('delete', '<a href="deletePo/$1"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >Delete</a>', 'id');
```

how can i add confirmation on this action??

Comment: in your a tag add onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Remove?');"

Comment: tried it already shows syntax error :(

Comment: escape the single quote like this onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to Remove?\');"